# How is array variable is filled with values without initializing the variable with new keyword in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I have two cases and couldn't figure out how the codes are working please help. Thanks

**Case 1:**

```
Transform[] zombiesTransform;
private void Start() 
{
  zombiesTransform = new Transform[5]; // now i have initialized so i can add some transform in it 
                                       //  which is fine

}
```

**Case 2 :**

```
Zombie[] zombies;
private void Start() 
{
  zombies = FindObjectsOfType<Zombie>(); // how is this zombie array is filled with value without 
                                         // initializing zombies variable like "zombies = new Zombies[5]"
}
```

Comment: Becase _FindObjectsOfType<Zombie>_ internally creates the array and then returns the reference to this array to its caller. The caller (your code) assigns the reference to your array variable.

Comment: @Steve Now I understood.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to explain using an example (as if I were writing the code of `FindObjectsOfType`)

```
public T[] FindObjectsOfType<T>() where T : new() {
    T[] collection = new T[5];
    T[0] = new T();
    // create more T items
    return T;
}
```

So what am I doing here? I'm saying that the generic type `T` is new-able (I can create an object of it), I declare and instantiate a new array of `T` objects and then return them to the one needing them.

Comment: Basically because array is a reference so both `FindObjectsOfType` or `new T[5]` return a **reference** to an array.